# Strange effects when exporting an Arcmap file to Adobe Illustrator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, illustrator

I am working on a map in ArcMap (10.2) and when I went to check how some of my markers looked in Illustrator I got some odd results. Here is a picture of the error: 
[image: error]

If you look closely in the red circles, you will see gray lines of markers that belong to two different features, but not the actual markers themselves. Two of the markers that did not show in the image are the same as the black horse image that is drawn above. The rest of the map has the same problem. None of the rest of my file is rasterized, and everything shows up in the layers dialog as it should be. What could be causing this error when exporting?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Illustrator on the same machine as ArcGIS?  ArcGIS marker symbols are ESRI fonts that may not be available on the machine with Illustrator.  In that case Illustrator is replacing your fonts with default fonts.

Use the *convert marker symbols to polygons* and/or the *embed fonts* options on the export map dialog box and see if that solves your problem.